# While in if loopr in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, while-loop

I'm about to learn Ruby and kind of confusing to use while loop with if:

```
var = gets.chomp

while  var != gets.chomp.upcase  
    puts 'What? '
    if var == var.upcase 
         puts 'Yes!'
    else
    end
end
```

Which mistake did I do in that case? Because the `if` does not seems to be ok..

Comment: what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var = gets.chomp

while  var != var.upcase  
    puts 'What? '
    var = gets.chomp
    if var == var.upcase 
         puts 'Yes!'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing and clashing variables, using `var` for everything. Try to give more explicit names:

```
# read the initial word
initial_word = gets.chomp

# read a word, and store it in another variable
while other_word = gets.chomp.upcase
    puts 'What? '
    if other_word == initial_word.upcase 
         puts 'Yes!'
    else
    end
end
```